# Getting next results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table that is something like the one below.

```
id  | episode_number

1        55
2        56
3        57-58
4        59
5        60
6        61-62
7        63
8        64
9        65-66
10       67-68
```

How would I get the next 5 episodes after 57-58 without specificity the id, just the episode_number such as episode_number > 57-58 LIMIT 5.

But obviously episode_number > 57-58 would not work since it contains string in it. The database will just consider it as 5 and return the next 5 results after the episode_number 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CAST function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to convert string to number, then your query:

```
 SELECT episode_number
   FROM table_name
   WHERE CAST(episode_number AS UNSIGNED) > CAST('57-58' AS UNSIGNED)
   ORDER BY CAST(episode_number AS UNSIGNED)
   LIMIT 5
```

If there are two numbers, for example: '57-58', then `CAST('57-58' AS UNSIGNED)` converts and returns first one: 57

Comment: MySQL allows the following shorthand: episode_number+0

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tablename WHERE id >= (SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE episode_number = "57-58")
```

or if it's MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id >= (SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE episode_number = "57-58") LIMIT 5
```

Comment: TOP doesn't exist in mysql, you should use LIMIT, also order by is missing

Comment: What did I say about the id? Look the question above again. I said "..without specificity the id.."

Comment: Well you would not need to know the ID, the query would take care of that. You would only need to replace "57-58" with whatever you need. @KuwameBrown. I do this so that there is something unique and comparable to get the next episodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can select like this:

```
select id , case when LOCATE('-' , episode_number) = 0 then episode_number 
                 else  LEFT(episode_number , LOCATE('-' , episode_number)) end 
            as start_episode , 
            case when LOCATE('-' , episode_number) = 0 then episode_number 
                 else  RIGHT(episode_number , LEN(episode_number) -LOCATE('-' , episode_number)) end 
            as end_episode
```

this should give you the base structure for such queries, you should consider converting the values into numbers to be able to easily compare them. 
If possible restructure the table to something that has the start episode and end episode in separated fields

Comment: Too much stuff, this will slow down the query.

Comment: storing data like this as text in a database losses the meaning of the data. this shows how to create a better structure that correctly models the question's domain